# Match phone number and name in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

Complete excel noob here.
I have a .xlsx file that is automatically generated by a third-party software. This file has a list of names, some of which appear more than once.
I also have a "phonebook" file that contains phone numbers associated with the names from the first file.
What I'd like to do is make it so that everytime a name comes up, the cell in the adjacent column displays the associated phone number. I of course do not need to keep the two file separate.
I don't even know where to begin. Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: you need to use VLOOKUP its probably the most used function in excel

Comment: I learned how to use VLOOKUP and it does exactly what I needed! Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide a simple sample about this problem? About VLOOKUP function, please refer to this support article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1

Comment: @Wyrd good stuff ! welcome to SuperUser